# Google hosted libraries don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use Google hosted libraries for my site (and then jQuery an jQuery-UI local hosted). I pasted the script tags into the head and when I wrote a part jQuery I get the error:

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="slider();">
    <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="img/1.jpg" border="0" alt="1"/>
        <img id="2" src="img/2.jpg" border="0" alt="2"/>
        <img id="3" src="img/3.jpg" border="0" alt="3"/>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running this from a web server, or just loading a local HTML file? If it's local, you'll need to prefix the JS URLs with `http://`, not just `//`.

Comment: You usually also need to include jquery before jquery-ui. Try changing the order of those script tags.

Comment: I changed what you two said but now i get another error: TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: solved. thanks everybody for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you probably have a static site (without a web server running) so you need to specify the **http** or **https** in the script references:

The reason is that you can avoid setting the **http** or **https** in the scripts reference because later the browser will be do it for you taking the protocol that your web server is using but if you are running a static site there is no protocol which the browser could take (there is no http or https in the URL) so the script src could not be resolved.

Another issue could be the order that you are setting the scripts. I think that **jQuery** should be loaded before **jQuery UI**.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Jquery should be loaded before jquery ui (you wrote it but the example contains the issue)

Answer (score 2):

As indicated above JQuery must be called before JqueryUI since UI depends on JQuery. And yes include http if your site runs in http or https if your using https.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when your local scripts are running before jquery has been defined 'loaded'. Remember to wrap up your jQuery code in a onload statement.

```
$(function(){
    // jQuery code here!!
})();
```

Check out [jQuerys documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) on this for more info.